# OpenSwan + xl2tpd VPN: How can I share Internet connection

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I have an OpenSwan IPSec + L2TP VPN on Linux setup working from off of my server so I can connect to it from my laptop (roadwarrior setup).  I am able to connect to the VPN remotely just fine, however the internet connection is not shared.  I'm assuming there is some sort of masquerading I am supposed to be doing, but I have no idea how to go about doing that (iptables?).

Any help getting this working so I can essentially use my VPN connection as a proxy would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found my answer finally :)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.15.15.0/24 -j SNAT --to xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
```

Where xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa is the public interface I want to nat through, and the 10.15.15.0/24 is the private VPN network IP range I have set up.